# ASP.NET MVC file uploads using Valums Ajax Uploader no view created

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I followed this [tutorial](http://maxivak.com/asp-net-mvc-file-uploads-using-valums-plugin/), put js, css and gif in the respective folder. The problem is the view doesn't show a thing.

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/fileuploader.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/fileuploader.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="file-uploader">
    <noscript>
        <p>
            Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
    </noscript>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
action: '@Url.Action("upload")' // put here a path to your page to handle uploading
//,allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'] // user this if you want to upload only pictures
sizeLimit: 4000000, // max size, about 4MB
minSizeLimit: 0 // min size

 });
</script>
```

What is wrong with this script?

With Firebug the error generated is

```
missing } after property list
```

Page source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay">
                    [ <a href="/Account/LogOn">Log On</a> ]

            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            <link href="/css/fileuploader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/js/fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="file-uploader">
    <noscript>
        <p>
            Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
    </noscript>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
action: '/Home/upload' // put here a path to your page to handle uploading
//,allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'] // user this if you want to upload only pictures
sizeLimit: 4000000, // max size, about 4MB

minSizeLimit: 0 // min size

 });
</script>

        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the generated source? What do you see in Firebug?

Comment: I have added the generated source. See the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a trailing comma here that you should remove:

```
minSizeLimit: 0, // min size
```

And you forgot a comma here:

```
action: '@Url.Action("upload")' // put here a path to your page to handle uploading
```

So please make an effort to write valid javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
        action: '@Url.Action("upload")',
        sizeLimit: 4000000,
        minSizeLimit: 0
    });
</script>
```

Ah, I can see now that the article you have copy-pasted from contains the same error. Sorry, I thought it was your mistake. Feel free to notify the author of this article about the errors in his code.

Comment: It worked all now. Thanks. The problem was i missed the comma after action.

Comment: The earlier comment was for your first answer. Anyway, i removed it now.